# Site can't be reached issue for WEB API

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

Using Web API solution I'm downloading Excel file, But when I try to run that link I'm getting below error

"The webpage at https://test.quality.com/rmqwebapis/GetReport/278 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address".

Please help me out with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue could lie with the Winsock settings corruptions.

I suggest you to follow the steps below and check if it helps:

1. Right click on Start Menu and select Command Prompt (admin).
2. Type "netsh winsock reset" and hit enter.
3. When prompted, restart the computer.
4. Check if the issue persists.

If this problem only exists in chrome you can also refer to this [link](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/err_quic_protocol_error/).

Comment: I have followed the above steps still im facing same issue . Im facing the issue  in all browsers.

Comment: Can the default site be accessed normally?